# simple calculator in C# like this 6+4

Tags: c#, asp.net, console, calculator

these are the variables I used to save data in

```
int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string sign = Console.ReadLine();
int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

the if statement that check the input's

how to make it simple

```
    if (sign == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
            }
            else if (sign == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
            }
            else if (sign == "*")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
            }
            else if (sign == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong operation sign ...");
            }


        Console.ReadLine();
```

How to show the output in the form `num1 sign num2 = num3` e.g. `"6 + 4 = 10"` in the console window?

Comment: You want to show it in the format `num1 sign num2 = result`? Is that the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your result to a variable outside of your if/else statement so that you can "dynamically" build your output at the end.

```
var result = 0;
if (sign == "+")
{
    result = num1 + num2;
}
else if (sign == "-")
{
    result = num1 - num2;
}
else if (sign == "*")
{
    result = num1 * num2;
}
else if (sign == "/")
{
    result = num1 / num2;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong operation sign ...");
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}={3}", num1, sign, num2, result);  

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It works thanks a lot, 
at this point the user do the following 
enter num1 then press enter
enter the sign then press enter
enter num2 then press enter
and to get result too 
can it done by just type 6+4=result "I mean just press one enter to get the answer" Can I do that?

Comment: @Tarek yes, see my answer. Comment on it if you want more details

Answer (score 6):

Use string formatting:

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} = {3}",num1, sign, num2, num1 + num2);
```

For more information take a look at: [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and also  [`Console.WriteLine(String, Object)` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think you should set the operator as a parameter as well

Comment: I am upvoting you not because of your answer, but because you understood the question in the first place :D

Answer (score 0):

To print out the result u can do

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}={3}", num1, sign, num2, result)
```

where result is the result of the operation. (e.g. 6 in your example)

Answer (score 0):

`"how to make it simple?"`

You can abuse the DataTable.Compute method:

```
var answer = new DataTable().Compute(num1.ToString() + sign + num2.ToString(), null);
```

`"How to show the output..."`

See [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [console.WriteLine overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as mentioned by Selman22, eg:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} = {3}",num1, sign, num2, answer);
```

How your program could be written:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please type a simple sum:");
string sum = Console.Readline();
var answer = new DataTable().Compute(sum, null);
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",sum, answer);
Console.Readline();
```